# Mixing three colors together

Tags: graphics, rgb, procedural-generation

I'm writing an algorithm to generate images procedurally.

< Pseudocode >

```cpp
color1 = (7, 46, 76)
color2 = (119, 230, 161)
color3 = (148, 129, 134)

for every x, y in image {

   // do a crazy calculation to get a value based on x, y

     // this number is between 0 and 1
     float f = (output of crazy calculation)

     // part 1: finding the color between color 1 and color 2
     // according to f.
     float r = c1.r + (c2.r - c1.r) * f;
     float g = c1.g + (c2.g - c1.g) * f;
     float b = c1.b + (c2.b - c1.b) * f;
}
```

This works great for now. I can assign r, g, and b to a pixel and get something that is between those two colors. The problem is, its really boring.

What I want to do is mix this color with a third. An article I've been reading says to do this:

"start from a simple color ramp based on f, then mix the color to a third one based on the magnitude of q" <- q is a vector2, whose values are between 0 and 100.

^ https://iquilezles.org/articles/warp/

My "Color Ramp" is color1 and color2. Somehow, I need to mix in color3.

I don't know what the article means. I know magnitude is sqrt(qx^2 + qy^2), but I don't know how it wants me to mix in color3 with the (r, g, b) color according to this value.

How would you mix in a third color?

Thanks,
Rylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following quote from your pseudo code is linearly interpolating two colors together based upon a fractional number.

```
 float r = c1.r + (c2.r - c1.r) * f;
 float g = c1.g + (c2.g - c1.g) * f;
 float b = c1.b + (c2.b - c1.b) * f;
```

This operation is called often called “lerp” for short. In GLSL the same operation is called `mix`.

I think the article is suggesting that you take the result of mixing `c1` and `c2` and then mix  that with a third color based on the magnitude of `q`, calculated as you described.

Following on from your pseudo code, and assuming that we have the magnitude of `q` in a variable `qm`, mixing in the third color could be written like this:

```
 r = r + (c3.r - r) * qm;
 g = g + (c3.g - g) * qm;
 b = b + (c3.b - b) * qm;
```

You may want to either scale down `qm` so it is between 0 and 1, or clamp it to be at most 1.